# Why mongoose is changing the _id when I use its findOneAndUpdate method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I came from relational database whereas the primary key (this case, _id) is the same along its life, and so I was surprised when I saw this behavior in mongodb.

I'm using the mongoose's findOneAndUpdate plugin method in the below way:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "products._id": _id, "_id": req.payload._id },
  {
    $set: {
      "products.$": { name: "New name" },
    },
  },
  {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  },
  function (err, doc) {
    if (err != null) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({
          message: "Error on updating. Please, try again later.",
        });
    } else if (doc == null) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found." });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(doc.products);
    }
  }
);
```

Before start:

```
{_id: 58b5e637f9f904a800721abf, name: "Old name"}
```

After **(_id changed)**:

```
{_id: 58b5e35a7f4ff38c433a5bc9, name: "New name"}
```

I just want to keep the same _id after an update, 'cause I think I could to face troubles when I implement a simultaneous updates for example.

I searched and I found out this mongoose method is called straightforward to the mongo's drivers without middlewares. Thus, I guess this question can be solved by experts in mongodb without knowledge in mongoose.

Comment: Seems like to me it created a new entry. Why is your document doesn't have `products` part ?  Can you tell what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Of course. It's a 1 to N relationship whereas a user (store, in real world)  can have N **product** and a **product** has one user (store)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_id` is attached to a document revision, not a document entity.

By passing `new: true` you're asking Mongo to return the id of the latest revision, which will have a different id than the original document (Upsert).

For document based storages it's recommended to implement your own UUID schema.

Either go deterministic with [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-1345):

```
var UUID = require('uuid-1345');

UUID.v3({
  namespace: UUID.namespace.oid,
  name: "abc" // Some formula to calculate you uuid, could be based on the document's legacy id or some other unique identifier.
}, function (err, id) {
  console.log("Generated a name-based UUID using MD5:\n\t%s\n", id);
});
```

Or random with plain random HEX:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var id = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
```

Include this in your document's body... and don't forget to [index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) it!

Comment: This is very misleading.   `mongodb` never changes `_id` with `findOneAndUpdate` but with `upsert:true` in the options, it might insert a new one.   Whatever `mongoose` is doing is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is happening is local to your `mongoose` space.  **Under *no* circumstances will mongodb `findOneAndUpdate()` *change* the `_id` of a matching document but if `upsert:true` it might create a new `_id`**